# File not found when using FacebookSDK with React Native < 0.40.0

Tags: xcode, facebook, reactjs, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using React Native `0.37.0` (because my project uses [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) which is yet to support RN >= `0.40.0`) and attempting to use the Facebook SDK.

I've followed the instruction steps on [react-native-fbsdk's npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk), fully; and double-checked to ensure everything is installed, all the search paths are added etc.

When running my project in XCode I get a Buildtime error in the `RCTFBSDK` library. In the file `RCTFBSDKAppEvents.h`: `'React/RCTBridgeModuke.h' file not found`.

[image]

The import line in that file is the new syntax for React 0.40.0:

`#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>`

Is there anything that I can do to make these versions of frameworks play together? I need the navigation library and the facebook one, so until I find a solution I'm completely blocked.

Anything else I can share to support an answer, just ask.

Comment: Shouldn't it work if you just change the name back to the > 0.40 import statement? `#import React/RCTBridgeModule.h`

Comment: @MattAft Unfortunately this doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you are running the latest version of react-native-fbsdk which only works with RN `>= 0.40`.

Try uninstall react-native-fbsdk:

`npm uninstall react-native-fbsdk --save`

Then, reinstall with an older version:

`npm install react-native-fbsdk@0.4.0 --save`

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to work out which bit of code needed to change. This worked right away.